# Change numbering color in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice-writer, numbering

I'd like to change the background color of numbers in a numbered list in LibreOffice Writer. Currently I have the following.

[image]

Selecting these lines (and also lines above and below) and choosing Format | Character | Highlighting | No fill has no effect.

The paragraph style of these lines is Default Style. When I edit Default Style in Styles and Formatting (F11), I don't see any sign of a different color: Font Effect tab has Font color as Automatic, Outline & Numbering tab has Numbering Style as None. I want to stress that I don't believe the change of color was done by editing styles in any way, and so I would like a way to change it back to white also without styles if possible.

I also would like to be able to format numbers in other ways: to choose size, apply bold, etc.

Answer (score 0):

By default, numbered lists use the `Numbering 1` list style.

[image: list style]

Right-clicking on the style and choosing *Modify* shows that the Character Style for level 1 numbering is `Numbering Symbols`.

[image: customize numbering style]

So, find that style under Character Styles and modify it.

If the formatting was done directly instead, then select the whole list and go to *Format -> Clear Direct Formatting*.