# remove numbering in heading but keep the sub-heading numbering

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

Problem: If I remove the numbering from Heading1 with backspace, Heading2 numbering becomes 0.2.

Question:I want to remove the heading number from Heading1 but I want to keep Heading2 as it is.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the numbering is calculated automatically, but we can work around this by formatting the numbering for Heading 1 so that it cannot be seen.

1. In the Character Styles sidebar, right-click on Default Style and choose *New*.  Name it "Hidden".
2. Font Size: `2`, Font color: white, check *Hidden*, OK.
3. *Format -> Bullets and Numbering -> Customize*.  Level `1`, Character style: "Hidden".
4. Go to *Position* tab. Level `1`, Numbering followed by: `Nothing`.

[image: invisible numbering]

More information about formatting the numbers:

- [Change numbering color in LibreOffice Writer](https://superuser.com/questions/1258622/change-numbering-color-in-libreoffice-writer)
- https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/60393/bold-numbering/