# How to enumerate only nested list in word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I want to create a custom list enumeration for a report so it support this format:

Chapter 1

1.1 Title one

```
 1.1.1 Subtitle one
```

Chapter 2

2.1 Title one

```
 2.1.1 Subtitle one
```

Meaning that chapters do not have enumeration but the nested list of each chapter do with relation to its parent.

Duplicate : [remove numbering in heading but keep the sub-heading numbering](https://superuser.com/questions/1310157/remove-numbering-in-heading-but-keep-the-sub-heading-numbering)

Answer (score 0):

Workaround found:

Edit the parent Heading so that it doesn't show the numbering, thus it does'n affect the sub-heading.